# f:uri.image inline-Viewhelper does not work

Tags: typo3, fluid

I am trying to access an `imageurl` via `inlinecondition` in fluid.

The none `inlineversion` works well and returns the URI of that image:

```
<f:uri.image image="{data.image.0}" />
```

returns:

```
fileadmin/user_upload/jumbotron.jpg
```

This one doesn't:

```
{f:uri.image(image:data.image.0)}
```

I have tried different versions with {}, without, with '' without ...

My environment is: TYPO3 8.2 (as I can't update cause extensions I need are only available till this version for now)

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Your syntax looks fine. {f:uri.image(image:data.image.0)} should work. This maybe a bug then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems this was a bug in 8.2 - After updating to 8.4 it works like charm.

This code works:

```
{f:uri.image(image:data.image.0)}
```

Comment: I also had that Problem in an 8.2 Environment.

Comment: Please consider to mark the question as answered if it's solved now. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try using `{f:uri.image(image:'{data.image.0}')}`, mind the escaping

Comment: Thx for the quick respons.
Oops, an error occurred!
You must either specify a string src or a File object.

More information regarding this error might be available online.